# Does a noble woman 'kick out' her child's wet nurse?

Tags: internal-consistency, society

**Backstory of the question (which will be used as the template for nobility in the city/region):**

Nobles are busy people. Too busy for silly things like breastfeeding and raising children -- not even their heirs. So, naturally, a wet nurse is acquired instead. Therein lies the dilemma. If a child is wet nursed by a woman other than the birth mother, they will undoubtedly form a strong bond with the wet nurse instead of (or as well as) the birth mother.

However, having a strong bond with 'lower class people' is ill advised even for 'poor nobles', let alone the true elite. So how does a society adapt to these stringent roles?

Is it wiser to 'kick out' the wet nurse from the child's life? Arguments based on the following (possibly unimportant) factors:

- Wet nurse is (likely) a slave, albeit a well-treated one.
- Birth mothers (generally) are not jealous, but aren't brought up knowing love either, and therefore cannot offer it.
- Plausible loyalty conflicts. Birth parents can never doubt their progeny's loyalty, or they are apt to kill them before it becomes an issue.
- Set in a very cut-throat environment. If killing someone is more effective than helping them, that's the path most taken; family bonds are irrelevant.

(Note: if there are suggestions to better the question, please let me know?)

Comment: Excommunication as I understand it only be done by the Pope.

Comment: Try dictionary.com for a decent answer

Comment: Replace 'excommunicate' with 'kick out'. The point is whether the wet nurse should be allowed to maintain ties with the MC.

Comment: Fayth85, this is a question of what a character should do in a situation rather than building a world.  When an answer necessitates someone else deciding what your characters should choose to do that is generally off topic.

Comment: It really depends. If you look at historic examples, these children were truly raised in an odd manner. Being "presented" to their mom and dad once a month or so, addressing them only with formal titles, etc. They themselves were also addressed by their titles, and the staff had a servant - ruler relationship with the children. They would grow up feeling very confident and entitled, and I don't think that such attachments would necessarily form. Most likely their wet nurse would become just one in a series of servants who've come and gone.

Comment: @James - I understand that. I've changed the wording to show it's to figure out what the precedent would be that the MC's parents are most likely to follow, not what would/should happen in this one instance.

Comment: The precedent would still be based on the decisions of characters.  Now if you were to ask, as one particular example, how this was managed in Earth's history that could potentially be on topic.

Comment: That's exactly the problem. It's not based in Earth's history, or even anything similar to it. The closest I could go is saying this is set a few thousand years into the future, but even that is a stretch. What I'm basically trying to figure out, is: "On a broader scale, spanning hundreds if not thousands of years, what would nobles become accustomed to doing in this situation?" But, frankly one could still argue that this is 'character choice'. It's honestly tempting me to delete the question and stop getting my hopes up for some kind of discussion to help me see other points of view.

Comment: @James - Better?

Comment: @Fayth85 That may be the crux of the issue.  SE is not a discussion site/forum.  I am not saying this is not an interesting question just that it is perhaps not a great fit for the site's format.  I am sure if you bring the question to [chat] for example people would be happy to discuss it with you.

Comment: @James - Alright. So what is the better option for this question? Reword, or toss?

Comment: @Fayth85 C'mon over we can chat:  http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/17213/the-factory-floor

Comment: It's really not big deal, It was for long time, and was solved differently. Milk brothers, specially if they are similar(one is bastard) are useful resources. It is important to choose wet nurse right, because she have to be loyal, specially in cut-throat environment, she might be noble it self, but not that kinda noble which may participate in some not good deals and get something useful from them. She can be maid of honor. Not noble, but very loyal person(if you understand what I'm talking about) might be wet nurse. Loyal people, specially not noble, are very very valuable resources.

Comment: But if there would be highly trusted and respected House of wet nurses, with 1000years of history, then they could be constant choose. Because in history this was solved differently because there was absence of universal solutions, which works and available each time.

Comment: @MolbOrg Yes, I understand exactly what you mean. I'll take that into consideration, thanks ^_^

Comment: @BryanMcClure you mean excommunication from the _Catholic_ church. You can get excommunicated from other churches.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it is physically possible to wet nurse through age 7. In Western Europe and especially England, this wasn't the case, it was a much shorter period, from months to a year or two--likely if you've researched, you already know that. With the shorter period of time, the bonding problem is a bit solved. Early on, wet nurses took their charges home, but because of a high rate of deaths (because the wet nurse would share the milk with her own child) the custom became that the wet nurse would live with the nobles. Wet nurses got great food and nutrition. If the child thrived, they could get a recommendation to move to another noble house directly after, so that their milk never went out. Nobles often kept a "nurse" for the kid that wasn't the wet nurse afterwards, often a woman experienced in child care, but a little too old to be wet nurse. Sometimes it would be a woman who cared for a noble family generationally--so she might be a nurse who cared for the mother or father when she was young and is now taking care of the the child of that mother or father. It sounds as though you don't want to write this other character/get them out of the way because it complicates things. If that's the case, just kill her off, for extra pathos. However, this can be a rich opportunity. Kids who are cared for by people other than their parents often find any time spent with their parent to be very valuable, because they don't have day-to-day interactions with them. It's not that the noble doesn't love the child--the whole reason why they give them a wet nurse/nurse is because they want them to thrive. It really depends on the type of parent. For the neglectful type--look to the first few chapters of *[The Secret Garden](http://read.gov/books/secret-garden.html)*. It's from Victorian times, but it does follow Medieval tradition, a bit. Here's [a link](https://www.care.com/a/8-ways-to-have-a-great-relationship-with-your-nanny-1011091102) to a modern site on healthy relationships with parents and nannies.

Edit: Romeo and Juliet is another great literary example. The nurse, I believe was Juliet's wet nurse. [Here's a link to an interaction where Lady Capulet starts to send the nurse away, then thinks better of it, because of the relationship.](http://www.opensourceshakespeare.org/views/plays/play_view.php?WorkID=romeojuliet&Act=1&Scene=3&Scope=scene&LineHighlight=452#452) As you can see, the nurse knows her kid better than Lady Capulet does.

Go to TV tropes and click on the Nurse Character in [this link](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Characters/RomeoAndJuliet) to see all the tropes she hits.

Comment: I didn't know there was a scene in Romeo and Juliette about that, thank! No, I would actually prefer to keep the wet nurse for drama purposes, but I need to know if that makes sense. No matter how dramatic, if it goes against the grain, it's unlikely to be practical and therefore can ruin the reading experience.

Comment: Juliet was weaned at about 2 1/2 or 3 years old, going by the text--the method used to wean her is covered. Like any mom, Nurse has got embarrassing stories about Juliet as a small child. The nurse is one of my favorite characters--she's bawdy (notice her saying that women grow bigger by men, referring to pregnacy and sex) and talkative. It's a great interaction. Lady Capulet basically tells her to talk less, Juliet is embarrassed by the story. As for practicality, there's lots of historical precedent. Noble ladies employed people like her for hundreds of years.

Comment: another example, cut from the same cloth, is the nurse/lady in waiting of Lady Marian in Robin Hood.

Comment: Interesting. It would definitely be something worth taking into consideration. Thanks!

Comment: Another take on the limited interaction with the actual parent, the child may end up resenting the parent for not taking as much of an interest in the child's life as they "should".

Answer (score 3):

Excommunication means to be excluded from The Fellowship of the church and can only be done by the Pope. I take it you mean something a little more secular, like Exile of some kind.

Suppose the wet nurse has done her job up until the child is 7, most seven year olds I know are very naive and trusting folk. Have the wet nurse exiled quietly, then simply tell the 7-year old that she died. The child will grieve but will probably survive to adulthood with minimal emotional damage I like other children who lose a parent at a young age.

Of course you could ask if it's a good idea to separate the child from the only source of Parental love we she? But seeing as the mother doesn't have or understand parental love she probably doesn't value it it's enough to keep her from excilling wet nurse.

Comment: It's unfortunately a bit more complex than I explain in the original question, but yeah. Long story short, the MC is 'advanced' for her age. So she isn't likely to be quite as naive. As for the 'parental love source', yes, that is one of the key problems. Thanks ^_^

Comment: Excommunication isn't exclusive to the Catholic church. Just saying.